# how to do one join to a table, Instead 2 joins on this table

Tags: sql, left-join

I need values City name and country name which is on Location table.
Below, I reached these values with using 2 joins on same table

But How to do it with one join instead 2 joins on same table?

I need to learn efficient solution?

```
select cus.*, l.name As 'City Name', lo.name As 'CountryName' 
from Customer cus
left JOIN Location l ON l.id= cus.cityId
left JOIN Location lo ON lo.id= cus.countryId
```

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do and how the schema is used.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with two joins, in my opinion.

Comment: just remove the `l.name as city_name` and remove `left JOIN Location l ON l.id= cus.cityId`.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an odd schema to have the location table host both cityID and CountryID values in the same column. I might prefer the two-join option as you have listed; however, if you are looking for another method, then you could use `conditional aggregation` with a `cartesian join`.

```
create table customer (
  id integer, 
  name varchar(10), 
  cityId varchar(10), 
  countryId varchar(10)
  );
  
create table location (
  id varchar(10), 
  name varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into customer values 
(1, 'John', 'ci101', 'co501'), 
(2, 'Sally', 'ci102', 'co502'), 
(3, 'Henry', 'ci103', 'co503');

insert into location values 
('ci101', 'Paris'), 
('ci102', 'Miami'), 
('co501', 'France'), 
('co502', 'United States'),
('co503', 'Spain');
```

---

```
select cus.id, 
 cus.name, 
 cus.cityId, 
 max(case when cus.cityId = l.id then l.name end) as city_name,
 cus.countryId,
 max(case when cus.countryId = l.id then l.name end) as country_name
from customer cus, location l
group by 1,2,3,5
order by 1,2;
```

| id | name | cityid | city_name | countryid | country_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | ci101 | Paris | co501 | France |
| 2 | Sally | ci102 | Miami | co502 | United States |
| 3 | Henry | ci103 |  | co503 | Spain |

---